# How to change box sizes in the Python code created by Abdelrazek Elnashar for Taylor diagram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, diagram

I'm trying to modify box sizes in the Taylor diagram that I created using the code in the below [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19WJ8L2NlWA7xrDhieHE1Zvi90hyZAjcR?usp=sharing).
I'd be so glad if someone could me explain how I can change the box sizes in the following code.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the call

```
dia.add_sample(i[0], i[1], label=i[2], c=i[3], marker='s')
```

you just need to add the argument `markersize`, e.g.

```
dia.add_sample(i[0], i[1], label=i[2], c=i[3], marker='s',markersize=12)
```

[See this link for details](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Adrian. It helps and works just great.